# Mirroring PC screen to Android via USB-C

Tags: usb, screen-mirroring

A few months ago I found software for Windows which could mirror Android screen to PC via USB (not sure if it needed to be type-C or not) and also capture mouse clicks as touch inputs.

I also know there is some software that mirrors PC screen to Android with Wi-Fi and such, but firstly they are not free and don't function as I want it to, and secondly, most of them use wireless which I don't want.

Is it possible to mirror (part of) PC screen to Android with USB-C?

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of apps that allow to remote control a PC from an Android device. You are correct that most of them use Wifi or in detail TCP/IP for communication with the PC. But some of those tools establish a direct TCP connection - hence using Android Debug bridge and `adb forward` you can forward the server port from your PC to your Android device and therefore tunnel the TCP connection through the USB cable.

On Android side in the app you then connect to `localhost:<forwarded port>`.

- [Microsoft Remote Desktop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.android) (Requires WIndows Pro edition or server)
- [VNC Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realvnc.viewer.android)
- [...](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=remote%20control%20pc&c=apps)

Each of this app requires a different software installed on your PC. Only Remote Desktop is bound to the used Windows type.

Comment: Hi, when searching to mirror screen to TV found that one. Do you know how to mirror android to TV? If yes, please answer https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/249990/mirror-screen-sound-preferably-to-tv-via-usb-c-hdmi-xiaomi-in-particular