# Mirror screen (+ sound preferably) to TV via USB-C/HDMI (Xiaomi in particular)

Tags: usb, hdmi, screencast, screen-mirroring

I did a web search and found only casting via Wi-Fi and/or cast to PC by installing some app on the PC.

Is there any way to mirror the screen to the TV from USB-C to HDMI (I have an adapter) of the TV? In particular, I'm interested in a solution for Xiaomi and TV that does not have Wi-Fi. Xiaomi screen casting in setting looks like it works only via Wi-Fi. If it's an app, preferably open source, or at least no registration and minimum of ads.

Comment: AFAIK USB2HDMI converters as they are typically used on PCs don't work as they work as a graphic adapter via USB. That requires drivers usually not included on Android. If you want to output display signal via USB-C check if your phone supported USB-C alternate display mode e.g. DisplayPort or HDMI. Usually this is a feature available in high-end Android phones.

Comment: @Robert, can't application doing mirroring contain the code for the conversion (same as said drivers have)?

Comment: Please note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not put any restrictions for apps-only. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: Drivers can not be installed on Android. Your kernel contains them or not. Could be possible but running everything in user land but Android apps don't have the permission to capture the screen of all other apps. Some apps are event blocked for security reasons. And of course an app would be running way slower than a kernel driver.